# clustered number index with star count

Tags: python

I have below pattern of stars

```
*
*
**
***
***
**
***
*
**
***
```

Based on that above pattern I have to generate numbered index like below.

```
1
2
2.1
2.1.1
2.1.2
2.2
2.2.1
3
3.1
3.1.1
```

I am trying with loops but not able to find how to generate sub indexes. I am trying in python.
Is there any library or algorithm that I can use to achieve this.

Comment: It's not clear what your generating function is. Show the function you are working with and whatever errors you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators): at each iteration, bring the list of indexes to the length of the stars and then increment the last index.

```
def gen(stars):
    inds = []
    for star in stars:
        if len(star) > len(inds):  # length should not increase by more than one ...
            inds.append(0)
        while len(star) < len(inds):  # ... but can decrease by more
            inds.pop()
        inds[-1] += 1
        yield '.'.join(map(str, inds))

>>> stars = ['*', '**', '***', '**', '***', '***', '***', '*', '**', '***']
>>> list(gen(stars))
['1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.2', '1.2.1', '1.2.2', '1.2.3', '2', '2.1', '2.1.1']
```

Also see the docs on [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) that are used for convenience.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your pattern is in a file `"tempfile"`, you can use the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("tempfile") as f:
    content=f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
arr=[0,0,0,0]
for line in content:
    arr[len(line)-1] = arr[len(line)-1]+1
    arr[len(line):]=[0] * (len(arr)-len(line))
    tarr=arr[:len(line)]
    print ".".join(map(str,tarr))
```

**Explanation :**

- Keep a memory array with all elements as 0
- For each line, count the number of asterisks,
- For a line with number of asterisk as n, increment the memory array with index = n-1 by 1,
- Assign all indexes to right with value = 0.
- Repeat logic for all lines.

**Output**

```
1
2
2.1
2.1.1
2.1.2
2.2
2.2.1
3
3.1
3.1.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your star pattern is stored in string `s`, here's one way to do it efficiently:

```
i = [0]
for l in s.splitlines():
    while len(i) < len(l):
        i.append(0)
    while len(l) < len(i):
        i.pop()
    i[-1] += 1
    print('.'.join(map(str, i)))
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
2.1
2.1.1
2.1.2
2.2
2.2.1
3
3.1
3.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build up a dictionary from your lines and print the whole dicts numbers after each line you parsed:

```
text = """*
*
**
***
***
**
***
*
**
***"""

d = {}
for l in text.splitlines():

    # add key if needed (with 0) 
    d.setdefault(l,0)
    # increment key
    d[l] += 1

    lenL = len(l)
    # delete any key in the dict that is longer then the actual one
    delete = [k for k in d.keys() if len(k) > lenL]
    for k in delete:
        del d[k]

    # from 3.7 on dict insert order is guaranteed - you could skip the sorting
    # sort keys by length and print theire respective values
    all_keys = sorted(d.keys(), key=len) 
    print('.'.join( ( str(d[k]) for k in all_keys) ), 
          "\t                from ", d) # this line just to display the dict
```

Output:

```
1                       from  {'*': 1}
2                       from  {'*': 2}
2.1                     from  {'*': 2, '**': 1}
2.1.1                   from  {'*': 2, '**': 1, '***': 1}
2.1.2                   from  {'*': 2, '**': 1, '***': 2}
2.2                     from  {'*': 2, '**': 2}
2.2.1                   from  {'*': 2, '**': 2, '***': 1}
3                       from  {'*': 3}
3.1                     from  {'*': 3, '**': 1}
3.1.1                   from  {'*': 3, '**': 1, '***': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of counts which will keep track of each level. Increment current level, and reset all levels next to it.

```
stars = ['*', '*', '**', '***', '***', '**', '***', '*', '**', '***']
counts = [] # to keep track of level counts
numbered_index = [] # will contain the numbered index

for s in stars:
    # if there are more levels than already known, initialize them with 0
    counts = counts + [0] * (len(s) - len(counts))
    # increment the current level count
    counts[len(s) - 1] += 1
    # the counts up to current level contain the index, join them in a string
    numbered_index.append('.'.join(map(str, counts[:len(s)])))
    # set all the values ahead of current level to zero, as the current level has been increased
    counts[len(s):] = [0] * (len(counts) - len(s))

print('\n'.join(numbered_index))
```

Output:

```
1
2
2.1
2.1.1
2.1.2
2.2
2.2.1
3
3.1
3.1.1
```